# Google CSE - Search bar is too big

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

My boss wants me to implement Google's CSE into our site.  So far, I've managed to integrate it on our test site and it displays properly when viewing the site through Firefox.
http://postimg.org/image/7maah372n/

However, the same search bar stretches across the header when viewed in Chrome.
http://postimg.org/image/4unnn732v/

Obviously, we can't implement this change on the live site until we've fixed this issue.  I used Google's CSE tool for this and it generated the following code.

```
(function() {
    var cx = 'custom site ID here';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
})();
```

This is enclosed by script tags, which were included with the code and a div tag used for CSS styling that was there with the old search bar.  What can I do to get this search bar working correctly for both Firefox and Chrome?  I've looked at the CSS for the div tag and the only thing that's there is position: relative and float: right.

EDIT: I've played around with the CSS for the div tag, setting the width to 230 pixels.  This works, but it seems like a less-than-desirable solution that may not hold up on lower-resolution displays.  Is there a way to make this more universal?

Comment: You could look into using `em` or `%` as it will set sizes according to either parent elements or the browser.